# Nodejs websocket net.socket file descriptor

Tags: c, node.js, sockets, websocket, file-descriptor

Is there anyway to get the C "FD" of socket object from a websocket object  in nodejs.

Currently I am working on proxy code in C/C++ that runs on a server and when a websocket connection gets established to this proxy I fork a child process and pass the socket's fd that represent my websocket to that child process. 
Since it is a child process it can open that socket from that child process and read and write to it using websocket protocol. 
This is all to avoid IPC.

Now I want to switch my proxy code to Nodejs and the process that I fork is still going to be implemented in C.

So I want to be able to read the socket object from the websocket object and query the file descriptor of that socket since it is implemented in C under the hood.

Comment: Does your design open a new process each time there's a new Websocket connection? IMHO, I would reconsider this design. It's hardly scalable and it could open your server to DoS attacks. Did you read [the paper on C10K](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html)?

Comment: I ll read it. Yes a new connection has to open a new process. There is authentication check on both websocket server up on connection and also an authentication check in the process. Actually the process uses 2. factor auth.if auth fail process exits.  I agree there's a scalability problem. better approach would be a regular IPC over sockets so I can create the process on other vms. But this is the spec unfortunately. Thabks for the input.